# How can I get Dex-to-Damage for two weapons or an off-hand weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I am looking into building a melee character who is Dex based and specializes in two weapon fighting.

Is there any way to apply my Dex mod to damage for my weapons, or at least just my offhand weapon? Feats, classes (and prestige classes), items and so on are welcome. No third-party products or D&D 3.5 materials allowed. I'm just starting out, and not sure how to do this yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are currently three methods to gain Dex to damage on the off-hand weapon.

#### Use [Agile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/agile) weaponry

This +1 equivalent weapon enchantment from the PFS Field Guide does the trick without any issues for finesseable weapons. Benefiting from this enchantment requires Weapon Finesse. Though the bonus on the off-hand is still halved. Contrary to the other two options, this one also applies when throwing these weapons, since it doesn't mention *melee* damage rolls.

#### [Fencing Grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/fencing-grace-combat)

This feat from Advanced Class Origins works only with full-sized rapiers, which are not light weapons, meaning you are looking at a -4 penalty for two-weapon fighting. However, it *does* lack the clear dual-wielding clauses of similar feats such as [Dervish Dance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dervish-dance-combat) or [Slashing Grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slashing-grace-combat). Instead, it only mentions "wielding a rapier one-handed", which doesn't explicitly forbid TWF. Dex to damage is *instead of* Str to damage, so it follows the rules for halving on the off-hand.

#### Be an [Unchained Rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained)

Pathfinder Unchained's Unchained Rogue class is an upgrade to the regular Rogue in 90% of the cases. One of the best new class features is [Finesse Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained#TOC-Finesse-Training-Ex-), which allows to choose a single finesseable weapon and use Dex instead of Str for the damage bonus at level 3.
As above, this damage bonus is halved for the off-hand (though it is also increased to 1.5x for two-handed finesseable weapons, such as [this one](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spear-elven-branched)).

Comment: To comment towards fencing grace and TWF. Using effortless lace on your off-hand weapon makes the down side of having 2 one handed weapons far less drastic.

Comment: @GarrickMoore [Effortless Lace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/effortless-lace) only makes a weapon count as light for the purposes of using feats, spells, and special abilities. It does not really *make* a weapon light, and it also does not make it count as light for the purposes of calculating the penalties for two-weapon fighting.

Comment: Fencing Grace got reprinted into Ultimate Intrigue with the added text "You do not gain this benefit while fighting with two weapons or using flurry of blows, or anytime another hand is otherwise occupied", as I understand it, this is now the official Fencing Grace, superseding the one in Advanced Class Origins.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to apply dex to damage(though reduced to half dex for off-hand(double-slice being the logical though not explicit, solution)) in the form of the Agile weapon. It does require you to be using Weapon Finesse compatible weapons and have the feat as well thought.

It can be found in the Pathfinder Society Field Guide, D20pfsrd.com, http://archivesofnethys.com. Possibly others.

Answer (score 0):

A good combo with the Agile Weapon property or Fencing grace would be using the new fighter [Advanced Weapon Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Advanced-Weapon-Training) "Effortless Dual-Wielding"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39457)

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: It's definitely [not link-only if the *names* are enough (as they certainly are here) to find the relevant rules independently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). A quote would be nice, or more explanation, but neither is strictly required.